# PHP's range function in Java

Tags: java, php, function, range

PHP's range function work like this in php :

```
$leap_years = range(1900, 2000, 4);
```

creates array like `1900, 1904, 1908, ...`
Is there something simple like this in Java?

Comment: be aware that 1900 isn't leap.

Comment: @OP: Your definition of a leap year isn't quite precise... Years divisible by 100 and not divisible by 400 aren't leap years ;)

Comment: Thanks guys for remembering, even though I will leave like it is, this is not the purpose of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't anything built in for this, but it's relatively simple to implement such a range as an immutable `Iterable<Long>` (or `Integer` or whatever). Just create a custom `Iterator` that starts at the start value and then increment for each call to `next()` until you pass the end value. You have to decide how and if you want to handle high-to-low iteration and such as well, but it isn't hard. You could also do this as an unmodifiable implementation of `List` where the value for each index is calculated on demand (`start + index * increment`).

While your question refers to the creation of an "array" based on the range, an array full of the data on the whole range is often not needed, particularly if you just want to iterate through the numbers in the range. If that's all you want, you'll end up iterating through the numbers in the range *twice* to create an array or `List` and then read it. Using a lazy range iterator as I've described doesn't have this disadvantage. Additionally, a lazy iterator can easily be copied into a `List` if you do want all the values stored in memory directly. The only disadvantage of it in comparison to building an array is some autoboxing overhead.

Answer (score 3):

You should do it this way:

```
public int[] range(int start, int end, int increment) {
   if (start < end && increment < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
   if (start > end && increment > 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

   int[] values = new int[Math.abs((end - start) / increment) + 1];
   boolean reverse = start > end;

   for (int i = start, index = 0; reverse ? (i >= end) : (i <= end); i+=increment, ++index)
   {
       values[index] = i;
   }
   return values;
}
```

Comment: I guess this would not work with reverse ranges like `range(2000, 1000, 100);`.

Answer (score 1):

You could simulate it like this:

```
public int[] range(int startVal, int endVal, int increment) {
  if (startVal >= endVal) {
    //handle error or add option to go backwards
  }
  int count = ((endval - startval) / increment) + 1;
  int[] myArr = new int[count];
  for (int i=0; i <= count; i++) {
    myArr[i] = startVal + (i * increment);
  }
  return myArr;
 }
}
```

Comment: You can't use primitives with generics.

Comment: `ArrayList<int>` should be `ArrayList<Integer>`

Comment: Good point, thanks. I don't have Java here at work to test it. :(

Comment: @Drackir: Oohh. You're on your work: You have to work ;-) Or doesn't it matter if you are working or not? ;-)

Comment: @Drackir: I'm not sure, but... I don't think you can use `ArrayList<Integer>.toArray()` (which returns an `Object[]`) to cast it to, or use it as `int[]`...